# How do the Christmas decorations work?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

During this year's [winter event](http://www.wowhead.com/event=141/feast-of-winter-veil#items:0-2), you can get Christmas decorations for your garrison.

Do they last all year or until the end of the event? Can I turn them on and off as I please? How exactly do they work?

The description of the items are vague and I'm just wondering how they work before I start hoarding them or decide to sell them.

Comment: well, i can say that the halloween decorations are still there in my garrison, but cannot say for sure about the christmas ones, my garrison now has a mix of pumpkins and christmas trees haha

Comment: @ViniciusTerrabuio You are a very festive person, nothing wrong with that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is not specified on the item, the duration is infinite.

To use them you simply have to put them on your shelf in the fief, and you can change them any time you want (take care not to destroy your ancient decoration)

The only concern I have about garrison decorations are when the next extension will be available, if there is also a garrison in it or something alike, I don't know if decorations will be synchronized.

Comment: Also found some topics discussing that, for example: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/19287960379